# GIMP 2.8 Fatal Error while refreshing brush

Tags: gimp

I am trying to add a brush to the Brush folder in gimp (version 2.8)-> C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\gimp\2.0\brushes

I chenge the extension to desert.gbr from desert.jpg.
When I open up GIMP and refresh the Brush menu it gives me an error!

**Failed to load data:
Fatal parse error in brush file 'C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\gimp\2.0\brushes\gimp-obsolete-files\Desert.gbr': Unknown version 1067590.**

Can someone help with this issue?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a .jpg file is not GIMP BRush file (a.k.a. GBR).
The correct ways to transform an image into a brush is to open the image in GIMP itself,
and `file->export` it as a `.gbr` file into your brush directory.

An easier way is to open the image, copy it (`ctrl + c`) and select `edit->paste as->new brush...` from the menus - that will automatically select the correct file type and directories for you.

Unlike brushes, GIMP's patterns can be any image file - so you can copy an image directly into a GIMP's pattern resource directory, and you won't get an error like the one above.